# How can I replace one term in an R formula with two?

Tags: r, r-formula

I have something along the lines of

```
y ~ x + z
```

And I would like to transform it to

```
y ~ x_part1 + x_part2 + z
```

More generally, I would like to have a function that takes a formula and returns that formula with all terms that match "^x$" replaced by "x_part1" and "x_part2".  Here's my current solution, but it just feels so kludgey...

```
my.formula <- fruit ~ apple + banana
var.to.replace <- 'apple'
my.terms <- labels(terms(my.formula))
new.terms <- paste0('(', 
                    paste0(var.to.replace, 
                           c('_part1', '_part2'),
                           collapse = '+'),
                    ')')
new.formula <- reformulate(termlabels = gsub(pattern = var.to.replace,
                                             replacement = new.terms,
                                             x = my.terms),                                 
                           response = my.formula[[2]])
```

An additional caveat is that the input formula may be specified with interactions.

```
y ~ b*x + z
```

should output one of these (equivalent) formulae

```
y ~ b*(x_part1 + x_part2) + z
y ~ b + (x_part1 + x_part2) + b:(x_part1 + x_part2) + z
y ~ b + x_part1 + x_part2 + b:x_part1 + b:x_part2 + z
```

MrFlick has advocated the use of

substitute(y ~ b*x + z, list(x=quote(x_part1 + x_part2)))

but when I have stored the formula I want to modify in a variable, as in

```
my.formula <- fruit ~ x + banana
```

This approach seems to require a little more massaging:

```
substitute(my.formula, list(x=quote(apple_part1 + apple_part2)))
# my.formula
```

The necessary change to that approach was:

```
do.call(what = 'substitute',
        args = list(apple, list(x=quote(x_part1 + x_part2))))
```

But I can't figure out how to use this approach when both 'x' and c('x_part', 'x_part2') are stored in variables with names, e.g. `var.to.replace` and `new.terms` above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about working with the formula as a string? Many base R models like `lm()` accept a string formulas (and you can always use `formula()` otherwise). In this case, you can use something like `gsub()`:

```
f1 <- "y ~ x + z"
f2 <- "y ~ b*x + z"

gsub("x", "(x_part1 + x_part2)", f1)
#> [1] "y ~ (x_part1 + x_part2) + z"

gsub("x", "(x_part1 + x_part2)", f2)
#> [1] "y ~ b*(x_part1 + x_part2) + z"
```

For example, with `mtcars` data set, and say we want to replace `mpg` (x) with `disp + hp` (x_part1 + x_part2):

```
f1 <- "qsec ~ mpg + cyl"
f2 <- "qsec ~ wt*mpg + cyl"

f1 <- gsub("mpg", "(disp + hp)", f1)
f2 <- gsub("mpg", "(disp + hp)", f2)

lm(f1, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = f1, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         disp           hp          cyl  
#>    22.04376      0.01017     -0.02074     -0.56571

lm(f2, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = f2, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           wt         disp           hp          cyl  
#>   20.421318     1.554904     0.026837    -0.056141    -0.876182  
#>     wt:disp        wt:hp  
#>   -0.006895     0.011126
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `substitute` function for this

```
substitute(y ~ b*x + z, list(x=quote(x_part1 + x_part2)))
# y ~ b * (x_part1 + x_part2) + z
```

Here we use the named list to tell R to replace the variable `x` with the expression `x_part1 + x_part2`

Comment: This seems very promising.  How would I handle the case where the formula I want to use substitute on is stored in a variable?  Seems like the substitute function works on the expression I put in the first argument, not the value of that expression?

Comment: It's unclear to me how exactly you are "storing" the variables not your question. I'm not sure exactly which part of substitute is unclear to you.

Comment: I've added some text at the end of the question, where I can do better syntax highlighting.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, then you just want to use `do.call` to pass in the value of the variable. `do.call("substitute", list(my.formula, list(x=quote(apple_part1 + apple_part2))))`

Comment: Ah, just bumped into another issue with this.  What about when the term to replace and the terms to replace it with are also stored in variables?

Comment: For the former case use setNames and the latter just don't use quote(). In the future try to make your initial question more complete or create a new question with new issues that arise. Changing the question in comments is not helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a recursive function to modify the expression tree of the formula:

```
replace_term <- function(f, old, new){
  n <- length(f)
  if(n > 1) {
    for(i in 1:n) f[[i]] <- Recall(f[[i]], old, new)

    return(f)
  }

  if(f == old) new else f
}
```

Which you can use to modify eg interactions:

```
> replace_term(y~x*a+z - x, quote(x), quote(x1 + x2))
y ~ (x1 + x2) * a + z - (x1 + x2)
```

Comment: The built-in `substitute` function does basically this.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to modify main effects, you can subtract x, and add in the two new variables.

```
> f <- y ~ x + z
> update(f, .~.-x+x_part1 + x_part2)
y ~ z + x_part1 + x_part2
```

Comment: How can you make x_part1 from x?

Comment: I did it with characters (`paste`) and then applied `as.formula` and passed that to the 'new' argument of `update`.

Comment: ah, the problem with with answer is that if the original formula has interactions, I believe they are lost in the new formula.  I'll update the question to make this scenario clear.

Answer (score 1):

As requested by `rcorty`, storing 'x' and c('x_part', 'x_part2') in `var.to.replace` and `new.terms`, respectively, and adotping `MrFlick`'s suggestion to use `setNames`, we could perhaps do the following:

```
my.formula <- fruit ~ x + banana
var.to.replace <- "x"
new.terms <-  c('x_part', 'x_part2') 
new.terms1 <- paste(new.terms, collapse="+")
do.call("substitute", list(my.formula, setNames(list(str2lang(new.terms1)), var.to.replace))) 

> fruit ~ x_part + x_part2 + banana
```

As an aside, I have found Paul Johnson's [Rchaeology](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rockchalk/vignettes/Rchaeology.pdf) (Section 2.1) relevant, educational, and entertaining.

Comment: this is golden.