# Comprehensively replace one term in an R formula with variants on that term

Tags: r, formula, substitution

I posted [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854510/how-can-i-replace-one-term-in-an-r-formula-with-two) yesterday.  During the course of reading and responding to answers, I came to better understand what I was trying to ask.  It was pointed out in the comments that I was "changing the question" and so I should post a new question.  Here's the new, better-thought-out, question!

I have the following situation, where `unknown.function` is what I am trying to implement:

```
my.formula <- fruit ~ apple * banana + carrot + apple
var.to.replace <- 'apple'
new.terms <- paste0('(', 
                    paste0(var.to.replace, 
                           c('_part1', '_part2'),
                           collapse = '+'),
                    ')')

result <- unknown.function(my.formula, var.to.replace, new.terms)

print(result)
# fruit ~ (apple_part1 + apple_part2) * banana + carrot + (apple_part1 + apple_part2)
```

MrFlick suggested the following definition of `unknown.function`, which seems to be promising.

```
unknown.function <- function(formula,
                             to.replace,
                             replace.with) {
    replacer <- list(replace.with)
    replacer <- setNames(object = replacer, nm = to.replace)
    result <- do.call(what = 'substitute',
                      args = list(formula, replacer))
    return(result)
}
```

But the result of this function is just a tad off:

```
print(result)
# fruit ~ "(apple_part1+apple_part2)" * banana + carrot + "(apple_part1+apple_part2)"
```

Specifically, the new terms are in quotes, which seems to get in the way of being able to use `result` as a typical `R` formula:

```
all.vars(result)
# "fruit"  "banana" "carrot"
```

Ideally, 'apple_part1' and 'apple_part2' would variables in `result`.

Comment: The problem really is with mixing strings (character values) and proper symbols (or expressions). They are not interchangeable without transformation. You want to store all your variable names as strings always? And if you pass in a vector to `replace.with`, you always want to insert them as a sum (`+` in between)? The string `"(apple_part1+apple_part2)"` is very different than the expression `(apple_part1+apple_part2)`. Why not just create the formula correctly in the first place rather than trying to change the formula.

Comment: Try as.formula(result)

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point.  I'm making a package and one of the design decisions I made was to let users be kind of sloppy with how they specify the input formula and I will take care of parametrizing it in the truly appropriate way internally.  This may have been a bad design decision...

Comment: specifically, this package deals with genetics and I want users to be able to say `formula = trait ~ genetic.marker.name` when they really mean `formula = trait ~ genetic.marker.name_additive.component + genetic.marker.name_dominance.component'`

Comment: Also try reformulate as described in this R man page https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/delete.response.html. Reformulate returns formula

Comment: Seems like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. It would be better to start with the original problem rather than fixing solutions. How would you know which terms to replace in the original formula? Would the user pass the formula as one parameter and then a string with the name of the genetic marker variable as a second parameter? That seems quite odd.

Comment: MrFlick, thanks for your thoughtful comment.  I'm happy to provide a bit more context.  There is one big, complex object called an "experimental cross" that holds a bunch of information about one genetics experiment: (1) the non-genetic information about all the experimental organisms (age, sex, bodyweight, etc.)  (2) genotypes at all the sparse, but directly measured genetic markers (3) estimated probabilities of each genotype at every spot in the genome (based on HMM on the measured genetic markers)

Comment: This object is standard in the very popular `qtl` package.  I am working on a package that will work on that same object but do different modeling procedures (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vqtl/index.html if interested).    The user inputs a cross object and a formula, and I parse through the formula and determine which terms in the formula are genetic markers.  The ones that are, I want to replace with (marker.name_add + marker.name_dom).

Comment: very open to other designs that might make this process more coherent.

Comment: So the part that's not clear to me is how you "parse through the formula and determine which terms in the formula are genetic markers". It would be much easier for me to see how this function would actually be called and then the desired output. Don't use strings if you don't have to.

Comment: The 'cross' object has the names of all genetic markers.  Any term in the formula that's also the name of a genetic marker should be replaced.